# How to have multiple same start tags but single end tag?

Tags: xml, tags, context.xml, xmlconvert

So I have an .XML file which has a start tag

```
abc "some text">  <abc "some text" > </abc>...
```

This means two same start tags, but one single end tag...
How's this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, it's invalid markup.

**Every tag** has to be closed in XML!
(Except for processing instructions - which are not considered to be "tags").

Answer (score 0):

All start tags must have matching end tags in XML.  Your textual data is not XML if this property is untrue.

Note that your example has two other problems:

1. The `<` on the first `abc` opening tag is missing.
2. `"some text"` must be preceded by an attribute name and an `=` character.

So, this would be well-formed (meets the requirements for being XML):

```
<abc d="some text">  <abc d="some text" > </abc></abc>
```

For further details on what *well-formed* means, see [Well-formed vs Valid XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085).